Recursive search for all corrupted directories ("Structure needs cleaning")
Is there a tool I can use to recursively search through a directory to generate a list of all corrupted directories, ie, those impossible to open ("Structure needs cleaning")?
Ideally, is it possible to also list when the directory in question was last modified?

what kind of directory are we talking about? "Structure needs cleaning" is not an output of anything that I can think of, so I'm a bit confused where and when you encountered that?
